# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to use SQL code to create large database.

[This](https://github.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data) is my source file

I tried to execute this code in seeds.rb file

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
connection.execute("

CREATE TABLE `VehicleModelYear` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `make` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `model` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE `U_VehicleModelYear_year_make_model` (`year`, `make`, `model`),
  INDEX `I_VehicleModelYear_year` (`year`),
  INDEX `I_VehicleModelYear_make` (`make`),
  INDEX `I_VehicleModelYear_model` (`model`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

")
```

And it gives me error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
```

I checked SQL code with validators, no errors found.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: files are mysql and application DB is SQLite

Comment: check this http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

Comment: try   `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,` instead of `\`id\` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`

Comment: another option is to change sqlite to mysql in your gemfile